# Why my network error detection of my Ajax POST doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm making an Ajax POST call to myapp.appspot.com/upload while attaching an uploaded user document. Sometimes my network goes completely off and the response never comes. I need to show an error message, and I thought the `error:` part of Ajax would handle that, but no, no error message, no nothing.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("form#data").attr("action"),
    data: formData,
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'binary', // using jquery.binarytransport.js
    success: function (returnValue, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        // Default response type is blob
        saveAs(returnValue, "result.pdf");    // using FileSaver.js
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error")
        if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            // HTTP error (can be checked by XMLHttpRequest.status and XMLHttpRequest.statusText)
            console.log("Http Error: ", XMLHttpRequest.status,
                        "Http Error text: ", XMLHttpRequest.statusText)

        }
        else if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 0) {
            // Network error (i.e. connection refused, access denied due to CORS, etc.)
            console.log("Network Error: ", XMLHttpRequest.status,
                        "Network Error text: ", XMLHttpRequest.statusText)
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error. Something weird is happening with the ajax request.")
        }
    }
})
```

What is happening?

Comment: if it's cross origin as you imply it should probably be a `type:jsonp` request. Also, pop a `console.log` into your success handler (at the top) to see whether an error is being thrown or not. Anything in the console window?

Comment: Do you mean it shouldn't work as it is configured now? Because it works most of the time, except when I simulate some network failure (i.e. when I plug out the cable). Also, I've tested your suggestion but nothing gets printed to the console.

Comment: from jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ `Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.
Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.`

Comment: Omg I messed up. The crossdomain call doesn't happen there but inside the web server. Sorry. The Ajax call is pointed to my same .appspot domain, specifically it's pointed to myapp.appspot.com/upload